# How to resolve this error: The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I have a table in microsoft sql server management studio named Userdetails with column name `[Email address]` that has datatype `varchar(50)`. Now, I am accessing this variable in jsp to compare this variable with another variable named `email2` whose datatype is text.Unfortunately, I am getting an error.

This is only a part of my code.

```
String str=request.getParameter("email2");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select [Email address],Username from Userdetails where [Email address]='" + str + "');
```

Comment: Try using varchar(max) to store your email field in the database .

Comment: Instead of '=' (equal to operator) i used 'like' and it working without error.   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select [Email address],Username from Userdetails where [Email address] like '" + str + "'and day="+ str1+" and month like '" + str2 + "' and year="+ str3+"");

Answer (score 1):

First problem: you're including values directly in SQL. Don't do that - it's just asking for a [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com).

Instead, use a prepared statement with parameterized values. You may well find that that's enough to fix the problem.

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement
   ("select [Email address], Username from Userdetails where [Email address]=?");

// This may give the same problem...
pst.setString(1, str);

// but this may fix it
// pst.setClob(1, new StringReader(str));

ResultSet results = pst.executeQuery();
```

(Obviously only set the parameter one way or the other.)

Don't forget to close the statement in a `finally` block.

Comment: Sir, i am not getting what you are trying to explain.

Comment: @user936516: Previously you'd included the value *directly in your SQL*. That's a really bad idea, and I've presented the alternative. Search for "prepared statements jdbc" and "SQL injection attack" for more information.